# por que cuando le doy click al boton no me realiza la llamada?

Tags: android, android-studio

public class Puertas_Ventanas extends AppCompatActivity

```
        ImageButton Btn_Llamada; // declaro mi variable
```

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
         Btn_Llamada = findViewById(R.id.Btn_Llamada); // la inicializo
```

private void getllamada() {

```
    Btn_Llamada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:3584163062"));
            Log.e( "onResponse: ","se hizo la llamada");
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Puertas_Ventanas.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return;
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El teléfono debe tener el signo `+` antes del número, si no se tiene esto puedes ser causa por la cual no se muestra el número telefonico:

"tel:+3584163062"

al usar un `Intent`, este método no requiere permisos `CALL_PHONE`  en el 
archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` o requerirlos manualmente y el intent debe ser definido de esta forma:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Realiza el cambio:

```
Btn_Llamada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+3584163062"));
            Log.e( "onResponse: ","se hizo la llamada");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```